# Replace "WordPress" word in title of Dashboard

Tags: customization, title, dashboard

I would like to replace the `WordPress` word in title of Dashboard.

[image]

Original title:

```
Dashboard < Site Title - WordPress
```

Expected result:

```
Dashboard < Site Title - foobar
```

I tried to do this with this below code, but it doesn't do what I expected.

```
add_filter('admin_title', 'my_admin_title', 10, 2);
function my_admin_title($admin_title, $title)
{
        return get_bloginfo('name').' &bull; '.$title;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tried correct filter - just needs to update return:

```
function my_admin_title ( $admin_title, $title ) {
    return $title . ' ‹ ' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . ' — ' . 'foobar';
}
add_filter( 'admin_title', 'my_admin_title', 10, 2 );
```

Btw, filter above works only for logged pages, for login page needs to add another filter:

```
add_filter( 'login_title', 'my_admin_title', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about this area

[!Wordpress Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzFjv.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzFjv.png)

/wp-admin/options-general.php

[image: Wordpress Title Setting]

You should not have to insert in PHP

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for.